# SAT4J Implication use case

Tags: java, sat, sat4j

I'm new to sat4j library. How I can define implication e.g. `(A1 v A2 v A3) => (A1 ∧ A4)` using sat4j and find boolean values for all variables?

I had found unit test for sat4j than I have tried something like in listing below. Problem is that `hasASolution()` returns true but `solution` variable is empty.

```
DependencyHelper<String, String> dependencyHelper = new DependencyHelper<>(SolverFactory.newEclipseP2());
dependencyHelper.implication("A1", "A2", "A3").implies("A1").and("A4");
// Before get a solution it must be checked
assertTrue(dependencyHelper.hasASolution());
IVec<String> solution = dependencyHelper.getSolution();
System.out.println(solution.toString());
```

Comment: I find out another framework ([AIMA on github](https://github.com/aimacode/aima-java)) for logic operations that can do it in few lines. You can find some jUnit tests [here](https://github.com/aimacode/aima-java/blob/AIMA3e/aima-core/src/test/java/aima/test/core/experiment/logic/propositional/algorithms/WalkSATExperiment.java) as introdution to AIMA framework.

Answer (score 0):

solution provides you a list of "satisfied" variables. Here, falsifying the variables satisfy your implication.

thus the empty solution set means that all the variables are falsified.

Comment: Is there a way to force some variables be `true`?

Comment: @VadymPerepeliak Just a constraint/clause with a single variable. Something like 'formula.and (var)'